# Simpletest Cannot redeclare simpletest_autorun()

Tags: php, simpletest

A Simpletest test in MyTest.php that runs with no errors:

```
require_once ('simpletest/autorun.php');

class MyTest extends UnitTestCase {
    function test() {
        //Test...
    }
}
```

A SimpleTest test suite

```
require_once ('simpletest/autorun.php');
class AllTests extends TestSuite {
    function __construct() {
        $this->TestSuite('All tests');
        $this->addFile('MyTest.php');
    }
}
```

The error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare simpletest_autorun() (previously declared in  /Library/WebServer/Documents/Option/tests/simpletest/autorun.php:26) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/option/tests/simpletest/autorun.php on line 34

The (horrible) solution, change MyTest.php to:

```
if (!function_exists("simpletest_autorun")) {
    require_once ('simpletest/autorun.php');
}
class MyTest extends UnitTestCase {
    function test() {
        //Test...
    }
}
```

It appears that this example follows the documentation, it doesn't or SimpleTest has this bug?

Comment: The information you've omitted by replacing the full paths with *"dir"* in your error message is the key to finding the problem.

Comment: @Phil Updated with the full dir. I thought it was the same that's why I replaced. Looking with more care there's a caption 'o' difference

Comment: Well there you go. The OS X filesystem is case sensitive.

Comment: @Phil But it doesn't explain why different cases are being called. Taking in consideration that MyTest.php and AllTest.php are in the same directory calling require_once should yield different outputs

Comment: There's not enough information in this question to tell. Somewhere, you have some code that looks in `Option` and some other code that looks in `option`. Could even be configured in your `include_path` for all I know.

Comment: @Phil Jackpot! Changing include_path in php.ini from .../Option/classes to .../option/classes did the trick. If you'd update your question acordingly I can accept it.

Comment: Done. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume you have multiple copies of the SimpleTest `autorun.php` script.

Performing the `require` in your test case file attempts to include a second `autorun.php` file (different to the one included in your test suite) which defines `simpletest_autorun()` for the second time.

The fact that the line numbers don't match up adds credence to my assumption.

Looking at the **full paths** in the error messages should show you what's up.

Determine which copy you want to keep and remove the other, updating any incorrect paths in your code or configuration, including the `include_path` in `php.ini`.